# How to get reference to original data in case of exceptions?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm running some Callable threads using ExecutorService. The threads are initialized with data before submitting to ExecutorService.

When handling exceptions thrown by Future.get(), I'd like to log a message with the original data. Is it possible to go from the Future object back to the original thread that created it?

pseudocode:

```
void run(List<Data> dataList) {
    List<Future<Foo>> results = new ArrayList<Future<Foo>>();
    for (Data data : dataList) {
        Callable<Foo> thread = new FooCallable(data);
        Future<Foo> result = this.executorService.submit(thread);
        results.add(result);
    }

    ...

    for (Future<Foo> result : results) {
        Foo foo;
        try {
            foo = result.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            //
            // I would like access to the original Data object here
            //
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            //
            // and here
            //
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `FooCallable` is a `Callable`, not a thread.  The name there is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Map instead of a List to store your Futures and their corresponding Data, and use the Futures as keys into that map:

```
Map<Future<Foo>,Data> results = new HashMap<Future<Foo>,Data>();
for (Data data : dataList) {
    Callable<Foo> thread = new FooCallable(data);
    Future<Foo> result = this.executorService.submit(thread);
    results.put(result,data);
}

Iterator<Map.Entry<Future<Foo>,Data>> resultsIterator = results.entrySet().iterator();
while(resultsIterator.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<Future<Foo>,Data> entry = resultsIterator.next();
    Future<Foo> future = entry.getKey();
    Data data = entry.getValue();
    Foo foo;
    try {
        foo = future.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        //data accessible here
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        //data accessible here too
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to go from the Future object back to the original thread that created it?

I think you mean that you'd like to get access to the `Data` field that caused the exception.  You can do this by creating a little container class:

```
private static class FutureData {
   final Data data;
   final Future<Foo> future;
   public FutureData(Data data, Future<Foo> future) {
      this.data = data;
      this.future = future;
   }
}
```

Then when you create your future, you add a `FutureData` to you `results` list instead.

```
List<FutureData> results = new ArrayList<FutureData>();
for (Data data : dataList) {
    Callable<Foo> callable = new FooCallable(data);
    Future<Foo> future = this.executorService.submit(callable);
    results.add(new FutureData(data, future));
}
```

Then you can do:

```
for (FutureData futureData : results) {
    Foo foo;
    try {
        foo = futureData.future.get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
       // use futureData.data here
       ...
```